# How to make a customised QR Code Scanner using Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a QR Code Scanner in Flutter that has this type of border that helps users to focus on the scanner, has a border color (blue in this case) and a white background color and is running inside a container widget:-

[image]

How can I create such a QR Code Scanner in Flutter, so far, I have used [flutter_barcode_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner) package and it looks like this:-

[image]

This one is pretty simple but it is a little tough to focus on the square scanner because of no border and it doesn't look that good.
Here's how I implemented my QR Code Scanner:-

```
Future<void> scanQRCode() async {
    try {
      final qrcode = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
        '#00B9F1',
        'Cancel',
        true,
        ScanMode.QR,
      );
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        this.qrcode = qrcode;
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) {
            return Dialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 300,
                width: 250,
                child: Text(qrcode),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) to suit your needs

you can use it as a Widget

```
 class _QRViewExampleState extends State<QRViewExample> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  Barcode result;
  QRViewController controller;

  // In order to get hot reload to work we need to pause the camera if the platform
  // is android, or resume the camera if the platform is iOS.
  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      controller.pauseCamera();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      controller.resumeCamera();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: QRView(
              key: qrKey,
              onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
              child: (result != null)
                  ? Text(
                      'Barcode Type: ${describeEnum(result.format)}   Data: ${result.code}')
                  : Text('Scan a code'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In case it helps, I have extracted from the [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) QR scan library (now deprecated, use [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner) instead) the overlay it offers. This way you can apply the overlay to whatever feature you want.

**Desired Class**

```
Stack(
        children: [
          ...,
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Container(
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: QrScannerOverlayShape(
                  borderColor: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  borderLength: 20,
                  borderWidth: 5,
                  cutOutSize: scanArea,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ...,
        ],
),
```

**QrScannerOverlayShape Class**

```
class QrScannerOverlayShape extends ShapeBorder {
  QrScannerOverlayShape({
    this.borderColor = Colors.red,
    this.borderWidth = 3.0,
    this.overlayColor = const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 80),
    this.borderRadius = 0,
    this.borderLength = 40,
    double? cutOutSize,
    double? cutOutWidth,
    double? cutOutHeight,
    this.cutOutBottomOffset = 0,
  })  : cutOutWidth = cutOutWidth ?? cutOutSize ?? 250,
        cutOutHeight = cutOutHeight ?? cutOutSize ?? 250 {
    assert(
    borderLength <=
        min(this.cutOutWidth, this.cutOutHeight) / 2 + borderWidth * 2,
    "Border can't be larger than ${min(this.cutOutWidth, this.cutOutHeight) / 2 + borderWidth * 2}",
    );
    assert(
    (cutOutWidth == null && cutOutHeight == null) ||
        (cutOutSize == null && cutOutWidth != null && cutOutHeight != null),
    'Use only cutOutWidth and cutOutHeight or only cutOutSize');
  }

  final Color borderColor;
  final double borderWidth;
  final Color overlayColor;
  final double borderRadius;
  final double borderLength;
  final double cutOutWidth;
  final double cutOutHeight;
  final double cutOutBottomOffset;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => const EdgeInsets.all(10);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
      ..addPath(getOuterPath(rect), Offset.zero);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    Path getLeftTopPath(Rect rect) {
      return Path()
        ..moveTo(rect.left, rect.bottom)
        ..lineTo(rect.left, rect.top)
        ..lineTo(rect.right, rect.top);
    }

    return getLeftTopPath(rect)
      ..lineTo(
        rect.right,
        rect.bottom,
      )
      ..lineTo(
        rect.left,
        rect.bottom,
      )
      ..lineTo(
        rect.left,
        rect.top,
      );
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final width = rect.width;
    final borderWidthSize = width / 2;
    final height = rect.height;
    final borderOffset = borderWidth / 2;
    final mBorderLength =
    borderLength > min(cutOutHeight, cutOutHeight) / 2 + borderWidth * 2
        ? borderWidthSize / 2
        : borderLength;
    final mCutOutWidth =
    cutOutWidth < width ? cutOutWidth : width - borderOffset;
    final mCutOutHeight =
    cutOutHeight < height ? cutOutHeight : height - borderOffset;

    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = overlayColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final borderPaint = Paint()
      ..color = borderColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = borderWidth;

    final boxPaint = Paint()
      ..color = borderColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOut;

    final cutOutRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      rect.left + width / 2 - mCutOutWidth / 2 + borderOffset,
      -cutOutBottomOffset +
          rect.top +
          height / 2 -
          mCutOutHeight / 2 +
          borderOffset,
      mCutOutWidth - borderOffset * 2,
      mCutOutHeight - borderOffset * 2,
    );

    canvas
      ..saveLayer(
        rect,
        backgroundPaint,
      )
      ..drawRect(
        rect,
        backgroundPaint,
      )
      // Draw top right corner
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          cutOutRect.right - mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.top,
          cutOutRect.right,
          cutOutRect.top + mBorderLength,
          topRight: Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        borderPaint,
      )
    // Draw top left corner
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          cutOutRect.left,
          cutOutRect.top,
          cutOutRect.left + mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.top + mBorderLength,
          topLeft: Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        borderPaint,
      )
    // Draw bottom right corner
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          cutOutRect.right - mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.bottom - mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.right,
          cutOutRect.bottom,
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        borderPaint,
      )
    // Draw bottom left corner
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          cutOutRect.left,
          cutOutRect.bottom - mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.left + mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.bottom,
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        borderPaint,
      )
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          cutOutRect,
          Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        boxPaint,
      )
      ..restore();
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return QrScannerOverlayShape(
      borderColor: borderColor,
      borderWidth: borderWidth,
      overlayColor: overlayColor,
    );
  }
}
```

**How it looks** (red color chosen)

[image]

Comment: Hi @AlejandroQS, in this case how are you using the scanWindow parameter for MobileScanner widget? As it looks like the scanWindow parameter is not related to the Positioned.fill() widget.

Comment: Hello @MinhDanh! I don't use scanWindow on my project. I use the basic MobileScanner with a controller and an onDetect on the first position of a Stack. Lower on the stack code I have Positioned.fill(child: Container(decoration: ShapeDecoration(shape: QrScannerOverlayShape( . . .