# How to customize the Flutter barcode scanner

Tags: flutter

I'm using the Flutter barcode scanner. What I'm able to achieve is like

[image]

But what I need is like this.

[image]

Same question was asked here. [How to make a customised QR Code Scanner using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964433/how-to-make-a-customised-qr-code-scanner-using-flutter). But I want to customize using the same Flutter barcode scanner package. Can anyone help me with this.

My code is

```dart
String barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
  '#00FFB6',
  'Exit',
  true,
  ScanMode.QR,
);
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner Did you try this package

Comment: But this one is in maintenance mode only. Is it fine if I use this?

Comment: Sure. They will fix those issue no need to worry

Answer (score 1):

You can use [qr_code_scanner 1.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner)  which give you ability to customize your scanner as shown below
[image]

Comment: But this one is in maintenance mode only. Is it fine if I use this?

Comment: its fine because the developer will fix bugs and minor enhancements will be considered. but if you want you can use https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner